# How to check whether array is multidimensional?

Tags: php

How can I check if an array is multidimensional?

I know something like this would work:

```
is_array($arr[0])
```

But is there a better way?

Comment: Is your array guaranteed to be *evenly dimensional* or can it be *jagged*, meaning `array('foo', array('bar'))` (a jagged array) would fail your above test.

Comment: That's good and fast

Answer (score 2):

`is_array($arr[0])` won't work if the first index is not an array. Perhaps the following is more accurate:

```
is_array($arr) && count(array_filter($arr,'is_array')) > 0
```

Comment: Something short-circuiting would of course be preferable (an `any()` implementation, which PHP doesn't have by default)…

Answer (score 1):

This should also do the trick:

```
if (count($arr) !== count($arr, COUNT_RECURSIVE)) {
    // do something .. 
}
```

[`count()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) with the COUNT_RECURSIVE flag will return another result if the array is multidimensional.

Comment: Generally a good solution if you know that all elements contain data, but if you have empty sub-array elements.... [demo](https://3v4l.org/ZmS8i)